# RecyclerView in nested ScrollView below CollapsingToolbar auto scroll

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `CordinatorLayout` in which there is `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and below it is `NestedScrollView` to achieve collapsing with:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Inside nested scroll view there is a `RecyclerView`. I need to auto scroll the `RecyclerView` to a particular position when the `Fragment` is called. Need to set it programmatically. Any help please.

Comment: Try with: layoutManager.scrollToPosition(10);

Comment: Or mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition( 10 );

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
        {
            binding.nestedScrollContainer.smoothScrollTo(0, binding.myRecyclerview.bottom)
            binding.myRecyclerview.nestedScrollBy(0, binding.myRecyclerview.bottom)
        },
        200

)
```